# How can I stop an UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat UIView Animation?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, ios7, uiviewanimation

I have the following code inside of a UIView subclass:

```
[element setAlpha: 0.0f];

[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations: ^{
    [element setAlpha: 1.0f];
} completion: ^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished) 
    {
        return;
    }
}];
```

Then when I want to stop the Animation I send the following message to the View itself:

```
[[self layer] removeAllAnimations];
```

But it does nothing... How can I stop the animation?

Comment: Don't forget to : `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: Try: `[self.layer removeAllAnimations];`, also, do you get any compiling warnings ?

Comment: No, maybe it is the place where I call [self.layer removeAllAnimations]. Should I call it inside of the view or in the ViewController which contains the view?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `removeAllAnimations` on `element.layer`, not `self.layer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed using the following piece of code:

```
- (void)restoreAnimations {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [element setAlpha: 1.0f];
    } completion:NULL];
}
```

And calling it in the ViewController.

Btw. Thanks a lot Malloc!