# stop animation using UIView in UILabel XCode

Tags: xcode, uiview, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I have a doubt about to stop animation in UILabel, 
I'm using a UIView to animate a UILabel, my code is similar to:

```
-(void)pickerRowTransformItem:(int)item{
    //Get UILabel
    UILabel *labelTem = (UILabel *)[self.picker viewWithTag:item];
    if (labelTem){
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.10
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                            labelTem.transform = tr //Scale transform;
                            labelTem.textColor = color //Change color;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         }];

    }
}
```

to stop animation, should I use?

```
-(void)pickerRowTransformItemStopAnimation:(int)item{
    //Get UILabel
    UILabel *labelTem = (UILabel *)[self.picker viewWithTag:item];
    if (labelTem){
        [labelTem.layer removeAllAnimations]; //stop animation??
    }
}
```

or, which is the best way to stop a animation?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following article will benefit you. I believe this person solved the same question that you have. Try adding `completion:NULL` to your code instead of `labelTem.layer removeAllAnimations`.

[How can I stop an UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat UIView Animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455357/how-can-i-stop-an-uiviewanimationoptionrepeat-uiview-animation?rq=1)

Comment: But, this options is not available in UILabel or UIView

Comment: @sgb004 Why does the animation have to stopped? Are you stoping it halfway through? Is it repeating?